# If foreign key is a primary key of another table why can it be null?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Primary key cannot be null, this is a rule. But why foreign key can? If it is also a primary key of another table.

Is it because it is not from the main table?

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server or SQLite? They are 3 different RDBMS - please tag only the RDBMS of interest.

Comment: @Irene . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  You should tag only with the database you are really using -- even though the answer doesn't actually depend on the database in this case.

Comment: Most of this is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Also ask exactly 1 clear researched non-duplicate question. Also "why" is not a meaningful question--it has no clear answer--ask "what". Also that "why" is probably not what you actually mean to ask. Please make a clear question about whatever you are trying to talk about in the last 2 sentences of your post. Find out how PKs & FKs work first. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214348/when-are-why-questions-okay https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323005/are-why-questions-allowed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165952/what-should-be-the-range-of-acceptable-why-questions-on-stack-overflow etc etc

Answer (score 1):

**Pointing to Primary Keys**

Foreign keys can *point* to primary keys of other/self tables. If it's null (or partially null), then it means it's doesn't have a referenced row.

**Pointing to Unique Constraints**

Foreign keys can also *point* to unique constraints as well; and these unique constraints can actually be nullable. Look at the example below:

```
create table person (
  id int primary key not null,
  first_name varchar(20),
  last_name varchar(20),
  constraint uq1 unique (first_name, last_name)
);

insert into person (id, first_name, last_name) values (1, 'Peter', 'Cantropus');
insert into person (id, first_name, last_name) values (2, 'Chad', 'Ensis');
insert into person (id, first_name, last_name) values (3, null, null);

create table car (
  brand varchar(30),
  owner_first_name varchar(20),
  owner_last_name varchar(20),
  constraint fkoc1 foreign key (owner_first_name, owner_last_name)
    references person(first_name, last_name)
);

insert into car (brand, owner_first_name, owner_last_name) values
  ('Renault', 'Peter', 'Cantropus');
insert into car (brand, owner_first_name, owner_last_name) values
  ('Lada', null, null);
insert into car (brand, owner_first_name, owner_last_name) values
  ('Sumi', 'Chad', null);

select * from car;
```

Result:

```
id  first_name  last_name
--  ----------  ---------
 1  Peter       Cantropus
 2  Chad        Ensis    
 3  <null>      <null>   

brand    owner_first_name  owner_last_name
-------  ----------------  ---------------
Renault  Peter             Cantropus       -- not null: has a referenced row
Lada     <null>            <null>          -- null: not referencing
Sumi     Chad              <null>          -- partially null: not referencing
```

As you see:

- Only the fully not null foreign key references a row in the other table.
- The partially null row does not reference a row in the other table (though may be partially validated under some circumstances).
- The totally null row does not reference a row in the other table either. **Even, considering there's a unique key that is (null, null)**.

Answer (score 0):

The nullability of foreign keys is determined by the `NULL` constraint.  That is, foreign keys can be `NULL`, indicating no relationship.

Of course, `primary key`s can never be `NULL`, so there is no danger that a `NULL` value would be confused with a match.